# How to add swipe feature to images within modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I could not find solution for swiping images in Twitter Bootstrap modal. Right now I am using

```
// Swipe feature
$('#myCarousel').swiperight(function() {  
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');  
});  
$('#myCarousel').swipeleft(function() {  
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');  
});
```

for Carousel which is basically loaded into Twitter Modal with

```
('.modal-trigger img').click(function(e) {
    $('#myModal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url')); 
});
```

And this is my [HTML structure](http://jsfiddle.net/ewyjucn7/).

So how can I add swipe effect to images even in modal window and load all images in that modal window?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include `jQuery Touchwipe Plugin (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch Gesten / Gestures, Wischeffekt / Wipe Effect)` and do the following:

```
$('#myCarousel').touchwipe({
   wipeLeft: function() { 
     alert('next')
     $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');  
   },
   wipeRight: function() { 
       alert('prev')
      $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
   },
   min_move_x: 20,
   preventDefaultEvents: false
```

});

here is [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ewyjucn7/4/)

Comment: Thanks Danis, but that is not what I am searching for.